# Maxima and Minima problems

Tags: maxima-minima

I'm having trouble with the following question about maxima and minima. 
I have to find the points of local extrema of the function,
$$f(x,y)= 12x^2y+3y^3-48x^2 - \frac{81}{2}y^2+72y-4.$$
So, I begin with 
$$f'(x)=24xy - 96x $$
$$f'(y)=12x^2 + 9y -81y +72$$
then 
$$24xy - 96x = 0$$
$$12x^2 + 9y -81y +72 = 0$$
solving this system yields solutions,
$$(0,1),(0,8),(3,4),(-3,4)$$

Comment: Please use MathJax. Use `$\frac{abc}{123}$` for $\frac{abc}{123}$ (fractions). Formatting tips [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: do you mean $f(x,y)= 12x^2y+3y^3-48x^2  - \frac{81}{2y^2}+72y-4$ or $f(x,y)= 12x^2y+3y^3-48x^2  - \frac{81}{2y^2+72y-4}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly applied the quotient rule in $f_y?$  It doesn't look correct, but the lack of formating make it difficult to follow your work.

Find the set of $(x,y)$ such that $f_x = 0$ and $f_y = 0$  Looks like you are well on your way on that front.

At each ordered pair identified, find $f_{xx}, f_{yy}, f_{xy}.$

find the signs of the eigenvalues of $\begin {bmatrix} f_{xx} & \frac 12 f_{xy}\\\frac 12 f_{xy} &f_{yy} \end{bmatrix}$

If the determinant of that matrix $< 0$ you have one positive and one negative eigenvalue.  In which case you have found a saddle point.

If it is positive, then they have the same sign (and the same sign as $f_{xx}, f_{yy}$) and you have a max or a min.  (i.e. both negative, you have a max.  Both positive, you have a min).

Comment: I think it was $\frac{81}2y^2$

Comment: @JohnDoe Likely correct, it was a bit of a mess.